# SDL2 + OpenGL access violation

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2, access-violation

This works fine:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 6);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);

    SDL_GLContext mainContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)SDL_GL_GetProcAddress);

    SDL_Event event;
    int running = 1;

    unsigned int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

But if I wrap the initialization into a class I get an access violation when I call glCreateShader even though I'm not getting any error messages when initializing SDL and OpenGL:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    WindowManager wm;
    if (!wm.Construct())
        return 0;

    SDL_Event event;
    int running = 1;

    unsigned int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER); //<---- access violation here

    ...        

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my WindowManager class with the relevant functions:

```
class WindowManager
{
public:
    WindowManager() = default;
    
    bool Construct()
    {
        if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0);
            return false;

        mWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, width, 
        height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 6);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);

        mContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(mWindow);

        if (!mWindow)
        {
             spdlog::error("WindowManager could not be created!");

             return false;
        }

        if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)SDL_GL_GetProcAddress))
        {
            spdlog::error("Failed to initialize GLAD!");

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    SDL_Window* mWindow;
    SDL_GLContext mContext;
};
```

If anyone could some shine some light on what the issue could be I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I notice that you were *not* checking for errors in your original version `(!mWindow)` and `(!gladLoadGLLoader ...)` but you are now.  Could it have been that there was an error code (possibly even a false error code) all along but now you're actually exiting because of it?

Comment: That change alone doesn't look problematic at all, probably your problem is in other parts of code we don't see. Consider making minimal complete compilable example (and make sure your problem is actually reproducing in this example, at least on your machine).

Answer (score -2):

Since I was compiling WindowManager into a dll and using it in a separate project, I essentially made two programs.

Program A had an initialized OpenGL context but Program B that was using WindowManager did not.

So I had to write a function to expose the glProcAddress to Program B in order to make raw OpenGL calls such as glCreateShader().